# Probability Density Function to Cumulative Density Function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-analysis, utility

I am reading on Stochastic Dominance (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_dominance) and few questions on PDF and CDF.

The paragraph I am looking at this:

[image]

Why is that $P[A\ge x] \ge P[B \ge x] $ leads to the cumulative density function $F_A(x) \le F_B(x)$?

Don't understand that part. Need some explanation on that... Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of the cumulative distribution function,
$$
F_A(x)  = \mathbb{P}\{A \leq x\} = 1- \mathbb{P}\{A \geq x\} + \mathbb{P}\{A = x\}
$$
so for instance when the probability distribution is continuous, $\mathbb{P}\{A = x\}=0$ and you get
$$
F_A(x)  = 1- \mathbb{P}\{A \geq x\}
$$
which implies the relation between the inequalities you point out.